# Flutter plugin development: Receiving calls from method channel when application using the plugin is terminated

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-method-channel

I am developing a flutter plugin that utilizes the method channels to communicate with the native mobile platforms.

I have a problem with receiving calls from both native sides when the application using the plugin is terminated.

I m using method channel - i have implemented a reverse background channel for communication, have set up the methodCallHandler on the flutter side, but as i have researched, the flutter engine is not attatched when the appliation is terminated, therefore i could not reveive the calls even if i use the background channel.

I have found something like [callbackDispatcher](https://medium.com/@chetan882777/initiating-calls-to-dart-from-the-native-side-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugin-7d46aed32c47), but i couldn't get it to work in my architecture.
Is there any way to achieve this form of coummunication, is the callbackDispatcher the way to reslove this issue?